# Missing post data when updating Select options with JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have two selects in a form:

- `input_licensee_list`: filled with possible options (Using an Ajax call)
- `output_licensee_list`: to get the selection from the user.

When I post the form, I get the list in `output_licensee_list`.

For this I added two buttons: Add (Move selected options from input to output), and Add All (Move all options from input to output).

```
// Add all button: remove all entries from input list and add them to output list
add_all_button.on('click', function (e) {
    var options = input_licensee_list.find("option").remove();
    options.append(' (' + group_selection.find("option:selected").text() + ')');
    options.appendTo(output_licensee_list);
    output_licensee_list.trigger('change');
    input_licensee_list.trigger('change');
});

// Add button: remove selected entries from input list and add them to output list
add_button.on('click', function (e) {
    var options = input_licensee_list.find("option:selected").remove();
    options.append(' (' + group_selection.find("option:selected").text() + ')');
    options.appendTo(output_licensee_list);
    output_licensee_list.trigger('change');
    input_licensee_list.trigger('change');
});
```

I have prepared a JSFiddle to show it:

https://jsfiddle.net/zaun8qgp/4/

The JQuery code itself seems to work fine, and the form is posted correctly if I use the "Add" button (Even if I select all options).

However for some reason, if I use the "Add all" button:

- The input `output_licensee_list` does not appear in the POST at all, so I do not get any information from it;
- If I use "Add", then "Add all", the information I get in the post if the list I initially added (before the Add All).

If anyone has clues on why it does not work correctly, or how I can debug more, I would appreciate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that submitting a from that contains a `<select>` **only submits selected options**. The options you add in the "Add all" are not selected.

The easiest way to fix this is to add:

```
options.prop('selected', 'true');
```

to you form submit event handler in order to make sure all options are selected before submitting.